# Where on my disk did Ubuntu install to?

Tags: system-installation

I installed ubuntu on my windows machine and during the installation time, I followed the first instruction which is side by side install ubuntu or something. now I can boot windows and ubuntu both pretty nicely. But I am wondering where the ubuntu installed? since I check the disk usage through the file manager on windows, nothing seems to changed... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well when you install ubuntu you would have set a specified partition(set amount of hard drive space) for it to install in. It doesn't look any different you would just have let's say 50 GB less hard drive space. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu run Disk Utility, and then look for the drive that is mounted at `/`. That will be your Ubuntu drive.

[image]